# When is tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: called in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` is sent to the delegate of a UITableView to find out how many rows it needs to have in a given section.

My question is, when and how often is this method called?

Comment: Why is that important?

Answer (score 6):

The method is called very first time the tableview is getting loaded and if you are more interested in the delegates then put a breakpoint and check when and where which delegate is called and how many times.

Comment: no in the case if you are setting the count in a static way and it will be called again and again if the count is coming from an array.

Comment: so if the count is coming from an array, it will call every time the count changes?

Comment: @Kasaname, yup I've just had a bug that's taken me ages to track down because that was the case. So annoying.

Answer (score 6):

Below are the instances when that function will get called,

1. For the first time when table is loaded
2. the time you reload the table data
3. the time you add/update/delete your row or sections dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

The method  `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` is a protocol method of the *UITableViewDataSource - protocol*. It will be called 
the very first time your table view is loaded based on that you have set the `dataSource` properly, e.g.

```
self.yourTableView.dataSource = self;
```

If you are interested in updating your table again at a later time you can call

```
[self.yourTableView reloadData];
```

in order to reload the entire table. If you are only interested in reloading a part of your table you can do something similar to

```
NSIndexSet *reloadSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.yourTableView])];
[self.yourTableView reloadSections:reloadSet withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, when and how often is this method called?

**Short Answer :** When your `UITableView` needs to update something.

**Long Answer :** Delegates Methods generally called themselves however it may be called multiple times when your `UITableView` needs to update something. By default, it's called very first time the tableview is getting loaded or updated (reloaded).

Comment: Okay, but when is that? I mean, what triggers the tableView to start call `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` etc besides when you call `reloadData`? Very hard to find an answer to that.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how often user will scroll UITable view to section and how many sections there are. This value, which is returned by this function and is casched. Method will need be revoked if you will update content of table view (filtering results, or updating data via **reloadData**).

Best thing for you will be to add logging to this function and check this yourself.