# How many times the function numberOfSections is called in tableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have some simple code:

```
class TestTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("toto")
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello world"
        return cell
    }
}
```

I was thinking, the function `numberOfSections` was called only once, when the tableView is loading or when we ask for reload.

But in my console with this code I have 6 "toto".

Can someone explain to me when they enter in the function `numberOfSections`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: called in UITableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914020/when-is-tableviewnumberofrowsinsection-called-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

numberOfSections gets called before loading the tableview. but i also gets called when you reloadData or delete or insert or update sections and cells. the code you provided is not enough to tell what is causing numberOfSections get called 6 times